# Kivy scrollbar scroll direction with mouse

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, kivy, python-2.x

Is there a way to change the scroll behavior of Kivy scrollbars when using a mouse?  With a mousewheel, the contents of a DropDown or Spinner scroll up or down as expected.  However, if you use a mouse to grab the scrollbar and slide it up, the direction is reversed - you have to drag the mouse pointer down to move the scrollbar and list up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be fixed by modifying the DropDown from which Spinner inherits to change scroll_type to include 'bars' (just 'content' by default).  I fixed this behaviour as follows:

```
from functools import partial

dropdownMod = partial(DropDown, bar_width = 10, scroll_type = ['bars','content'])

class SpinnerName(Spinner):
    dropdown_cls = dropdownMod
    values = ('1','2','3')
```